# How to change the size of activex control automatically?

Tags: activex, visual-c++, richedit

I wrote an activex control for showing images in richedit.What i want is the control's size changes as the image in it changes, but the control's size seems to be fixed, i've no idea how   to get it.Is there way to reach that?

Comment: I solved it. When image loaded,got image's width and height,then added codes like below:                                     AtlPixelToHiMetric(&sizel, &m_sizeExtent);
m_sizeNatural = m_sizeExtent;                                           I am a starter about activex, even didn't know how activex worked. think it's a silly question for old hands.

Answer (score 0):

Change the size of your ActiveX control's window with [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then call [IOleInPlaceSite::OnPosRectChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690287%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on your site object.

**[EDITED]** Apparently, you could perform the above upon [EN_REQUESTRESIZE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification from RichEdit. [EN_OBJECTPOSITIONS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also looks relevant. Try both and share the result with us.